# Error "database table and work area ... are not Unicode convertible"

Tags: abap

I've come across some strange error

> "The type of the database table and work area (or internal table) "<LS_P16>" are not Unicode convertible. convertible."

```
data <ls_p16> type pa0016.
modify pa0016 from <ls_p16>.
```

even though this small bit of codes gets this error.

do you know what I can do here or what might be the source of this error?

Comment: you can try this structure variable ; data ls_p16 type pa0016. modify pa0016 from ls_p16. if you want use field symbols check https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenabap_field_symbols.htm

Answer (score 2):

Angle brackets are prohibited for naming variables, they are [reserved for field-symbols](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abennaming_conventions.htm):

> Field symbols are special because their names have to be enclosed in angle brackets (<...>)

That's why you are getting an error, either rename the var or make it field symbol:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_p16> type pa0016.
MODIFY pa0016 FROM <ls_p16>.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like `DATA` use:

```
DATA: wa_p16 TYPE pa0016.
MODIFY pa0016 FROM wa_p16.
```

if you prefer `FIELD-SYMBOLS` instead, then...

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <ls_p16> TYPE pa0016.
MODIFY pa0016 FROM <ls_p16>.
```

Comment: Suncatcher has already pointed out the field-symbol issue. With a link to understand more.  A few minutes different can happen. People type answers at the same time.  But 8 hrs.   Seriously.

Comment: Wow man, really? Clearly sunscatcher's is the first answer and is a right answer. I was trying to give **both** possibilities of solving this. Yes, because there are two ways.